# Make the inner elements accessible when accessible={true} for the outer view in React native- iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, accessibility, accessible

I am very new to react native. I have a view which is having a text containing a url. I want to make the outer view accessible and then when the user swipes right it should focus on the url/link as we do in iOS.
For me when I make the outer view accessible={true} the inner elements will be non accessible.
And also I am not able to find out much content regarding the same. Can anyone give an insight on this.

```
 <View><Text>Some text</Text><View>
 <View><Text>Text with url</Text></View>
 </View>
```

As I mentioned above I want both outer and inner views accessible. It works fine in android but not in iOS.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: were you able to fix this? how?

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation on the above issue, I reached to a conclusion like, in iOS if we add accessibile={true} to the outer view , it will not allow the inner views to be accessible which is the default behaviour in iOS.  In android normally it works in the other way. Android equivalent of accessible property is 'importantForAccessibility'.